# Bug in a javascript digit counter

Tags: javascript

My script below checks that a form input contains at least 10 digits, besides other text. Everything works fine, except that it also counts spaces as a digit. Can anyone help with this bug?

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BG4du/

```
function(){
    var text = input.value;
    var totalNrOfDigits = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        if(!isNaN(text[i])){
            totalNrOfDigits++;
        }
    }
    if(totalNrOfDigits < 10){
        alert("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried: if(!isNaN(text[i]) && text[i]!=" " ){

Comment: So you need those spaces after all or not?

Comment: No spaces needed.  Amit Joki's solution works great!! thank you all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this:

```
function(){
    var text = input.value.replace(/\s/g,"");
    var totalNrOfDigits = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        if(!isNaN(text.charAt(i))){
            totalNrOfDigits++;
        }
    }
    if(totalNrOfDigits < 10){
        alert("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

`replace(" ","")` just replaces the first occurence. My solution removes all whitespace.

Answer (score 6):

According to MDN, [`isNaN` is broken](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description)

> Since the very earliest versions of the `isNaN` function specification, its behavior for non-numeric arguments has been confusing. When the argument to the `isNaN` function is not of type `Number`, the value is first coerced to a `Number`. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is `NaN`. Thus for non-numbers that when coerced to numeric type result in a valid non-`NaN` numeric value (notably the empty string and boolean primitives, which when coerced give numeric values zero or one), the "false" returned value may be unexpected; the empty string, for example, is surely "not a number." …

I'd recommend something like this instead:

```
var code = text.charCodeAt(index);
if(code >= 48 && code <= 57){
    totalNrOfDigits++;
}
```

48 is the character code for `'0'` and 57 is the character code for `'9'`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
function() {
    var text = input.value.replace(/\s+/g,""); //removes spaces
    var totalNrOfDigits = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        if(!isNaN(text[i])){
            totalNrOfDigits++;
        }
    }
    if(totalNrOfDigits < 10){
        alert("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: To add on, JavaScript considers `" "` to be `0`, and hence `!isNaN(text[i])` becomes `!isNaN(" ")` which is `true`.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Small correction, Javascript considers `Number(" ")` to be `0`.

Comment: @GaurangTandon Both are falsy, but that's not the same as being the same. `" " == 0` might hold, but `" " === 0` doesn't. `isNaN`, without looking at the spec, almost certainly will call `Number()` on string arguments which then evaluates to `0`.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the answers above:

```
function(){
    var text = input.value;
    var totalNrOfDigits = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        if(/\d/.test(text[i])){
            totalNrOfDigits++;
        }
    }
    if(totalNrOfDigits < 10){
        alert("Invalid input");
    }
}
```

[Here's an updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BG4du/1/)

Comment: That `+` in the expression is unnecessary since you are testing it on a single character. Same goes for `^` and `$`.

Comment: Thanks, habit more than anything. Updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use

```
var totalNrOfDigits = input.value.match(/\d/g).length;
if(totalNrOfDigits < 10)
    alert("Invalid input");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BG4du/3/)